# Put json data into url with python

Tags: python, json, http, url, mlab

I am trying to encode a json parameter within a url for use with the mongolab restAPI.

My url looks something like this

```
url = 'https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/db/collections/coll?q={"q": "10024"}&apiKey=mykey
```

I am trying to open it using

```
urllib2.urlopen(url)
```

but I run into errors saying that my apikey is incorrect. I know this isn't true because if I copy and paste the url into my browser I get  a correct response. I also know that I can access the rest api as long as I don't have the query there (so it must be a json/formatting problem).

So does anyone know how I could encode the json query

```
{"q": "10024"}
```

into the url? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to properly URL-encode the string. Use the [`urllib.quote_plus()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote_plus):

```
url = 'https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/db/collections/coll?q={q}&apiKey={key}'
query = urllib.quote_plus('{"q": "10024"}')
urllib2.urlopen(url.format(q=query, key=your_api_key))
```

Comment: worked perfectly for me. Thanks! Is there any quote_plus equivalent for urllib2?

Comment: No, there is no need. `urllib2` is an extension, not a full replacement.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the `requests` library.

Example:

```
import requests
payload = {'q': '10024', 'apiKey': 'mykey'}
r = requests.get("https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/db/collections/coll", params=payload)
print(r.url)
```

Output:

```
https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/db/collections/coll?q=10024&apiKey=mykey
```